# MySQL query that will find all the entries with a datetime within the last hour of a month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to get all records in a MySQL database where a `datetime` column's value is within the final hour of any month (i.e. January 31st 23:00-23:59, February 28th 23:00-23:59) etc.

Is there a way to write a query without writing a bunch of "BETWEEN" statements?

Suppose I have the following table:

```
id | createtime 
-------------------------
 1 | 2018-01-30 23:37:11
 2 | 2018-01-31 22:00:00
 3 | 2018-01-31 23:37:11
 4 | 2018-02-28 22:00:00
 5 | 2018-02-28 23:33:00
```

I want a query that would select rows `3` and `5` (the last hour of January and February respectively).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: could you provide some sample data  and expect result?

Comment: I edited it and added an example of exactly what data I want.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not really performant for loads of data, there is an option to use different [date/time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to accomplish this:

You can test it with this simple line:

```
SET @mytime = "2018-09-30 22:59:59"; 
SELECT 
  @mytime, 
  LAST_DAY(@mytime), 
  HOUR(@mytime), 
  DAY(@mytime), 
  DAY(LAST_DAY(@mytime)), 
  IF(DAY(LAST_DAY(@mytime)) = DAY(@mytime) AND HOUR(@mytime) = 23, 1, 0) AS is_final_hour
;
```

Just play with the datetime variable that is set at the beginning to see different results.

After that you can use it in a query like so:

```
SELECT
  t.mydatetime,
  IF(DAY(LAST_DAY(t.mydatetime)) = DAY(t.mydatetime) AND HOUR(t.mydatetime) = 23, 1, 0) AS is_final_hour
FROM
  mytable AS t
HAVING
  is_final_hour = 1
;
```